# Getting the value of an object in an array

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsarray

Thanks to a more expert user, I have implemented a method to sort core data objects inside a table view section. The sorting method inside the section is different to the sorting method of the table view. The latest is done by a NSFetchedResultsController. But now I don't know how to get the values from the sorted NSArray.
This is the method that sorts the core data objects inside a section:

```
- (NSArray*)sortedSectionForIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"priority" ascending:YES];
    id section = [[self fetchedResultsController] sections][index];
    NSLog(@"INDEX********* = %ld", (long)index);
    NSArray *objects = [section objects];
    NSArray *sorted = [objects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
    return sorted;
}
```

And this is the code added to the cellForRowAtIndexPat method to get the NSArray from the sortedSectionForIndex method:

```
 NSArray *sorted = [self sortedSectionForIndex:[indexPath section]];
    id object = [sorted objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSLog(@"OBJECTV= %@",object);
```

Now, I would need to know how to show the values from the array to be put as `cell.textlabel`:

A second question is that I don't know if getting the core data object from the array will change the way to handle them for the rest of the methods. I mean, before implementing this sorting method, when the user clicks on a row, a detail view from the selected object was shown. Now getting the objects from an array and not from the NSFetchedResultsController, I am not sure if it will continue working as before.

Comment: You've got the value right there -- you used objectAtIndex to get it!!  (I suspect what you're saying, though, is that you haven't a clue as to how to put a value into a label.)

Comment: No @HotLicks, the array has several keys (name, date, priority,etc.) what I need is to get the value of the name key in order to show it on cell.textlabel.

Comment: Well then, ask for the name key.  NSLog `object` to see what it is.  Is it a dictionary with a "name" element inside?

Comment: If you take a look at my question, NSLog object is already done..and yes there is a "name" element.

Comment: So what exactly does the NSLog look like.  Is it `{ name = "some name", number = 27, ...}`?

Comment: @HotLicks, yes, one row is:...data: {
    borrar = nil;
    isCompleted = notcompleted;
    isCritical = nocritical;
    isSomeDay = issomeday;
    isUrgent = nourgent;
    priority = c;
    quitar = nil;
    sectionIdentifier = 4;
    storedDate = nil;
    todoDescription = "Enter Task Description.";
    todoDueDate = "2065-11-12 07:00:00 +0000";
    todoName = "someday 1";
    todogroup = nil;
    todosubitems = "<relationship fault: 0x8922070 'todosubitems'>";
})

Comment: You said "one row is...".  Is there more than one row in `object`???

Comment: As we are inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, when I say one row I wanted to say a row example...., there is only one row in each object instance.

Comment: Well, I don't see "name" in your dump, so I don't know how you could fetch it.  You can't get something that's not there.  Now, if you wanted, say, "todoName", you'd first make `object` be an NSDictionary and then do `object[@"todoName']`.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the line

```
id object = . . .
```

To

```
NSManagedObject *object = . . .
```

And then

```
cell.textLabel = [object valueForKey:@"todoName"];
```